# Using a wrapped integer as index in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, wrapper

Assuming I have a (trivial) class that wraps normal int type in C++ for random integers, how can I use an instance of this class like an integer when indexing an array or picking a character from a string?

If it's a matter of operator overloading, then which operator?

As a specific example, I have a Random class and I pick characters at random locations in a string like this:

```
string chars = "whatever";
Random R = Random(0, chars.length());
other_chars += chars.at(R.getValue());
```

But instead, I'd rather have `other_chars += chars.at(R);` But how?

Answer (score 5):

You need a [user defined conversion operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr383.htm).

```
class Random
{
  int x_;

  public:
    operator int() const { return x_; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overloading `operator int()` inside the wrapper `Random`. I believe it should be something like,

```
class Random
{
  int value;
public:
  // ... constructors and operator =
  operator int () const { return value; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need typecast operator overloading: `operator int() { return _value; }`.

[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/) is more explanation.